# How to improve mysql NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE search query?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ("Apple M1" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

if I search `Apple M1` as results i get `Orange M1` then third or more position i get `Apple M-1` – which is the value i stored and I was assuming should be first!

my question is: there is a way to fine tune the mysql search?

Comment: If SQL natural language search isn't getting you the results that you need, I'd consider looking into syncing with a parallel Lucene database, like ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They best way to improve MySQL Natural Language Mode search is to use [Boolean Full-Text Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html) instead. It will do the same as Natural Language Mode search, but you can use additional modifiers to finetune your results, e.g. by

> **> <**
>
> These two operators are used to change a word's contribution to the relevance value that is assigned to a row. The > operator increases the contribution and the < operator decreases it.

There is one minor difference, boolean mode search will not order automatically according to relevance, so you have to order yourself.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST (">Apple M1" IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY MATCH (name) AGAINST (">Apple M1" IN BOOLEAN MODE) desc
```

And a remark: both versions of fulltext search will not find `M-1` if you match against `M1` (even with a minimum wordlength setting of 2). It will only look for exakt (usually case-insensitive) word matches, it does not look for similar words (unless you use `*`). It will "just" weigh the combination of (exact) words by some algorithm, and, if you use them, the modifiers.

**Update** Some additional clarification according to the comments:

If you match against `Apple M1`, it returns rows that contain (case-insensitive) `Apple` or `M1` in any order, so e.g. `M1 apple`, `Apple M4`, `Apple M-1` and `Orange M1`. It will not find `Apples M4` or `Orange M-1`, because they are not exactly that words. E.g. `like '%M-1%'` wouldn't find `Apple M1` either. But if you like, you can match against `Apple*` to find `Apple` and `Apples`, but it's always at the end of the word, `*Apple*` is not possible, you have to use `like '%Apple%'` then.

These rows are then ordered by the scoring algorithm, that will basically score words that are less common in your texts higher than very common words. And if you add `>Apple`, it will give `Apple` a higher value. It will just be a number, you can add them to your select, e.g.  `select ..., MATCH (name) AGAINST (">Apple M1" IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score` to get a feeling for that.

There are some other things to consider:

- only words that have a minimum length are added to the index. That length is given by `innodb_ft_min_token_size` for innodb or `ft_min_word_len` for myisam. So you should set it to e.g. 2 to include `M1` (otherwise, this word will not have any effect in your search. Since in your example, you found `Orange M1`, I assume it is set correctly).
- `-` is usually considered a hyphen. So `M-1` in your text will be split up into two words `M` and `1` (that may or may not be included according to your mininum word lenght setting, so maybe set it to 1). You can change that behaviour by adding `-` to the characterset (see [Fine-Tuning MySQL Full-Text Search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html), the part beginning with `Modify a character set file`), but this will then not find `blue-green` anymore if you search for `blue` and/or `green`.
- the full text search uses [stopwords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html). These words are not included in your index. This list includes `a` and `i`, so even with minimum wordlength of 1, you would not find them. You can edit that list.

Some ideas about your potential problem about `M1`/`M-1`. To adjust that to your exact requirements, you would have to add more information about your searches and data (and would be maybe another question), but some ideas:

- You can replace userinput that contains `-` by including both versions to your search query: once with `-`, but enclosed in `""`, once without. So if the user enters `Apple M-1`, you would create a search for `Apple M1 "M-1"` (that would work with or without a modified characterset, but without a new characterset, your min word length has to be 1). If the user enters `M1`, you should detect that and replace that by `M1 "M-1"` too.
- Another alternative would be to save an additional column with clean, hyphenless words and add that column to the full text index and then `match (name, clean_name) against ("M1" ...`.
- And you can of course combine like and match, e.g. if you detect a product number in your input, you can use something like `where match(...) against(...) or product_id like 'M%1%'`, or `where match(...) against(...) or product_id = 'M-1' or product_id = 'M1'` or even `where match(...) against(...) or name like '%M%1%'`, but the latter would probably be a lot slower and contain a lot of noise. And it might not score correctly, but at least it will be in the resultset.

But as I said, that would depend on your data and your requirements.

Comment: so, since my database is plenty of items with codes like [string][dash][number] should i combine UNION two select?... my users will unlikely search foe the exact string right?

Comment: @Francesco I added some info, maybe it will clear it up. If I understood you correctly, you don't need UNION to combine the words, the words are "OR"ed (and in any order), my point was that "M1" is not the same as "M-1".

Comment: OR yes... duh sometimes the easiest solution is just right there in front of you... thanks again!

Comment: also just as a reference you can see an example here (besides amazon of course!) https://reverb.com/marketplace?query=boss+dd7, the product name has a dash bu users upload or search for name without dashes

Comment: @Francesco Yes, but that problem is of course not limited to dashes. If someone doesn't know how to spell the word correctly (e.g. some authors name), the full text search will not find it. Just keep that in mind. It is especially strange when you don't find plural versions (but at least here, you can use e.g.`Apple*`) With product numbers in a know format, you might have a chance to circumvent that by manually adding additional versions of the word (in query or in db). But it is not trivial to make a good "spell correction", and you usually would do this with other search engines I guess.